# Xcode 4.6 where is code stored when I connect a button to a new view controller?

Tags: xcode

When working in the Storyboard/Interface Builder, does Xcode generate and insert some code at compile time that I don't get to see as I am browsing my header and implementation files?  If so, how do I view this code?

Consider that I added a UINavigationController and some view controllers.  I them placed a button on the first view controller and control dragged the button to the next view controller to make a connection/create a transition.  When I inspect my implementation I see no code reflecting this - should there be, and how do I get a chance to see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that is serialized within the storyboard.  The connection is made by you creating a segue object in IB.  This object exists within the storyboard and is automatically instantiated.  There is no visible code for these kinds of links; they are represented only in the storyboard.

Storyboards are awesome in that they can replace a lot of boilerplate code you used to have to write.  Unfortunately it takes some getting used to not actually seeing code that performs an action.

Answer (score 0):

Like @RichardBrown said, This is all done through the storyboard. There is no code to see through this. Ya it's kinda weird but its nice that you don't have to deal with code like that. Makes things a little easier on yourself